# how can i create custom view with a textview along with an edittext?

Tags: java, android

How can I make a custom view like this?

[image: Custom View]

All I need is an EditText and a TextView as a single control. And I need to give separate values and attributes to the EditText and TextView.

Comment: Can you explain a bit ,what kind of control you exactly want? You can see this link http://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/android-limited-character-textbox-custom-compoundview/ to have idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#c8b560"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="7dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="2dip"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name_value"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```